# Syntax for np.array([args.width, args.width]) and np.zeros(5)

Tags: numpy, argparse

I have a script that contains this part

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('out', type=str, help="Output file (.pkl)")
parser.add_argument('width', type=int, help="Frame width in px")
parser.add_argument('height', type=int, help="Frame height in px")
parser.add_argument('-f', type=float, nargs='?', help="Focal length in px (2,)")
parser.add_argument('-c', type=float, nargs='?', help="Principal point in px (2,)")
parser.add_argument('-k', type=float, nargs='?', help="Distortion coefficients (5,)")

args = parser.parse_args()

print args
camera_data = {
    'camera_t': np.zeros(3),
    'camera_rt': np.zeros(3),
    'camera_f': np.array([args.width, args.width]),
    'camera_c': np.array([args.width, args.height]) / 2.,
    'camera_k': np.zeros(5),
    'width': args.width,
    'height': args.height,
}
```

I tried to enter values for `f`, `c` and `k`, but it wasn't recognized.

For instance, I wrote `-f 800.0 600.0` and got `error: unrecognized arguments: 600.0`.
I tried `-f [800.0 600.0]`, `-f (800.0 600.0)` and `-f (800.0,600.0)` but none of them worked.
Also the whole web indexed by google did not come up with an answer to "How to enter an array into python as parameter?"

What syntax does the script require?

Comment: You can always change ```nargs=2``` and your first approach would work. But to be honest: Add the relevant tag ```argparse```, remove the misleading ```numpy``` (it's not touched at all) tag and start with reading the argparse docs. For us, the origin, quality and context of this script is completely missing.

Comment: @sascha https://github.com/thmoa/videoavatars/blob/master/prepare_data/create_camera.py is where it's from

Comment: With ? -f only accepts one number. Why the '?'?

Comment: Show a full commandline, not just the '-f' part

Comment: @hpaulj Look at the source code

Comment: This script can accept only one number for each of '-f', '-c', '-k'.  Looking at the rest of the code in the link I think the script should be using `nargs='*'` or `nargs=2` instead of `nargs='?'`.  The '?' is a mistake.

Comment: @hpaulj much better answer. It works now.